# How to add table headers in r

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I've made this table, but I want to add headers to my table which show the categories I'm comparing. At this point I've got this:

```
n <- c('like', 'must-be','neutral','live-with','dislike')

t <- table(factor(d$s1q4, levels = 1:5),factor(d$s1q1, levels = 1:5))
colnames(t) <- n
rownames(t) <- n
t
```

but now I want to add a name for `d$s1q4` and `d$s1q1` and make it show up in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `names` on the `dimnames`

```
names(dimnames(t)) <- c("s1q4", "s1q1")
```